# how to run windows on a computer without a hard drive using PXE

Tags: pxe-boot

We have some computers in a lab or computers for users and want to make it so they can boot
Windows 11 from a PXE server. Open to free and paid options.I would like to know what options are available.

Comment: PXE uses TFTP which won't work - the image would need to be kept in RAM. You'd need to use something like iSCSI and possibly booting initiator NICs.

Comment: Windows requires a minimum of 64 GB local hard disk storage. 

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-11-specifications 

There's almost certainly a better way to accomplish what you need.

Comment: Greg, it is possible and I agree at the point of the ISCSI, but also agree it is not so easy like running Linux from TFTP while using nfs